# Using awk to replace part of a line with the output of a program

Tags: bash, awk

I've got a file with several columns, like so:

```
13:46:48 1.2.3.4:57 user1
13:46:49 5.6.7.8:58 user2
13:48:07 9.10.11.12:59 user3
```

I'd like to transform one of the columns by passing it as input to a program:

```
echo "1.2.3.4:57" | transformExternalIp
10.0.0.4:57
```

I wrote a small bit of awk to do this:

```
awk '{ ("echo " $2 " | transformExternalIp") | getline output; $2=output; print}'
```

But what I got surprised me. Initially, it looked like it was working as expected, but then I started to see weird repeated values. In order to debug, I removed my fancy "transformExternalIp" program in case it was the problem and replaced it with echo and cat, which means literally nothing should change:

```
awk '{ ("echo " $2 " | cat") | getline output; print $2 " - " output}'   connections.txt
```

For the first thousand lines or so, the left and right sides matched, but then after that, the right side frequently stopped changing:

```
1.2.3.4:57 - 1.2.3.4:57
2.2.3.4:12 - 2.2.3.4:12
3.2.3.4:24 - 3.2.3.4:24
# .... (okay for a long while)
120.120.3.4:57 - 120.120.3.4:57
121.120.3.4:25 - 120.120.3.4:57
122.120.3.4:100 - 120.120.3.4:57
123.120.3.4:76 - 120.120.3.4:57
```

What the heck have I done wrong? I'm guessing that I'm misunderstanding something about awk.

Comment: Please describe how according to which rule 1.2.3.4 should be converted to 10.0.0.4.

Comment: I'm getting `- - -` on all lines from your second `awk` script given the example input

Comment: do you get any output when running `grep $'\r' connections.txt` ?

Comment: @Fravadona - No output.

Comment: @Cyrus - An arbitrary black box program named `transformExternalIp` takes in standard input like "1.2.3.4:47" and returns some arbitrary standard output, like "10.0.0.4:25". Output program will not print a newline at the end, for simplicity. I simplified to just use "echo (some input) | cat" as a no-op that also sees the problem.

Comment: What do you imagine `("echo " $2 " | transformExternalIp") | getline output; $2=output; print` would do inside `awk`? I can't understand what you want to do. Are you trying to construct a statement to send to bash? Are you trying to execute a shell command inside awk. If you can explain what you are trying to do with field 2 it will be easier to help.

Comment: @DavePritlove in a nutshell, yes, the code is executing a shell command (`echo $2 | transformExternalIp`) where `transformExternalIp` would appear to take its input from stdin (hence the `echo $2 | `; see [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline.html) for more details on the various uses of `getline`

Comment: Aside - use `"echo \047" $2 "\047 |` instead of `"echo " $2 " |` otherwise whatever $2 contains is exposed to the shell for globbing, word splitting, etc. and makes you vulnerable to DoS and other attacks. Also, f you're considering using `getline` then read http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close the command after each invocation to insure a new copy of the command is run for the next set of input, eg:

```
awk '{ ("echo " $2 " | transformExternalIp") | getline output
       close("echo " $2 " | transformExternalIp")
       $2=output
       print
     }'

# or, to reduce issues from making a typo:

awk '{ cmd="echo " $2 " | transformExternalIp"
       (cmd) | getline output
       close(cmd)
       $2=output
       print
     }'
```

For more details see [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline_002fPipe.html) and [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Close-Files-And-Pipes.html).

---

During my testing with a dummy script (`echo $RANDOM; sleep .1`) I could generate similar results as OP ... some good/expected lines and then a bunch of duplicates.

I noticed that as soon as the duplicates started occuring, the dummy script wasn't actually being called any more and instead `awk` was treating the system call as a static result (ie, kept re-using the value from the last 'good' call); it was quite noticeable because the `sleep .1` was no longer being called so the output from the `awk` script sped up significantly.

Can't say that I understand 100% what's happening under the covers ... perhaps an issue with how the script (my dummy script; OP's `transforExternalIp`) behaves with multiple lines of input when expecting one line of input ... an issue with a limit on the number of open/active process handles ... *shrug*

Comment: Excellent! This provides the fix, and @Fravadona provides the root cause: because I don't call close, I'm running into fork limits.

Comment: @BrandonYarbrough you might want to try `("transformExternalIp <<< "$2 | getline output`) as a means of eliminating the `echo |` and the extra process/fork, though I still ran into duplicates if I didn't issue the `close()`

Answer (score 1):

`("echo" $2" | cat")` creates a fork almost every time that you use it.

Then, when the above instruction reaches some kind of fork limit, the `output` variable isn't updated by `getline` anymore; that's what's happening here.

If you're using GNU `awk` then you can fix the issue with a [Coprocess](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline_002fCoprocess.html):

```bash
awk '
    BEGIN { cmd = "cat" }
    {
        print $2 |& cmd
        cmd |& getline output
        print $2 " - " output
    }
' connections.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Awk is a tool to manipulate text. A shell is a tool to sequence calls to other tools. Don't use a shell to call awk to sequence calls to transformExternalIp as if it were a shell, just use a shell:

```
while read -r _ old_ip _; do
    new_ip=$(printf '%s\n' "$old_ip" | transformExternalIp)
    printf '%s - %s\n' "$old_ip" "$new_ip"
done < connections.txt
```

When you're using awk you're spawning a subshell for every call to `transformExternalIp` so it's no more efficient (probably a bit less efficient) than just staying in shell.